# Can Presto connect to other Hadoop distributions and run queries

Tags: hive, presto

I see Presto has plugin only to CDH4. Can I connect to other distributions such as HortonWorks from this and what does it take to do it.
Without a specific plugin, I am running into "path host null" errors when executing queries from Presto. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

The Presto Hive connector supports multiple versions of Hadoop:

- `hive-hadoop1`: Apache Hadoop 1.x
- `hive-hadoop2`: Apache Hadoop 2.x
- `hive-cdh4`: Cloudera CDH 4
- `hive-cdh5`: Cloudera CDH 5

See the [Hive Connector documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Hadoop 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code for the CDH connector in GitHub?
 briefly looking at the code in GitHub, i dont see anything specific to CDH , other than the name, in presto / presto-hive-cdh4 /src / main /java - am i looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: The plugin's pom has a dependency on hive-cdh4: https://github.com/facebook/presto/blob/master/presto-hive-cdh4/pom.xml

The source for the hive-cdh4 artifact is here: https://github.com/facebook/presto-hadoop-cdh4

The actual code for the Hive connector is here: https://github.com/facebook/presto/tree/master/presto-hive